# Estimating the polynomial from only Y values

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

B has two polynomials of the same degree whose coefficients are defined over Zp and gives both polynomials to A. A picks a list of random X values, evaluates one of the polynomial and gives the result which is Y's values back to B. It is evident that he first evaluates then mod N.

Note: Both polynomials either are complete or have the same number of terms (e.g. ($x^2+1$ , $x^2+18$), as both have two terms is considered in our case, but ($x^2$ , $x^2+1$ ) is not allowed in here)

(1) Can B figure out which polynomial, A has used.

(2) What if two polynomials have different degrees. ** In this case the x values cab be defined as : x>(N/2)+1

Thanks

Comment: If $p$ is 1 less than a multiple of 3, then the polynomials $x^3+a$ are bijections for all $a$, so the $y$-values could come from any one of them. There are many more examples where just knowing the range of the polynomial doesn't enable you to deduce the polynomial.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Am I right to conclude that the B sometime is able to determine which one of the two polynomials has been evaluated at some unknown X's ?

Comment: Sure. If one of the polynomials is not a bijection, and you get a $y$-value not in its range, then it must have come from the other polynomial. B could just write out the range of each of the two polynomials and then look for $y$-values missing from one of the lists (provided the ranges weren't identical).

Comment: @GerryMyerson I'd like to ask this question please. If we define a polynomial over Zp. Then evaluate it on some (too many) $x$ values, to obtain y values (every operations are modp). Then we multiply each $y_i$ value by uniformly at random value chosen in Zp to obtain $y'_i$ value. We publish both $y'$ values and $x$ values. Can one obtain the original polynomial or any root of this polynomial given x values and y' values ? Many thanks

Comment: Well, to begin with, the polynomials $x^p$ and $x$ are identical as functions on ${\bf Z}_p$, so you wouldn't be able to tell them apart by their values under any circumstances. Also, you wouldn't be able to tell $f$ and $af$ apart, for any nonzero element $a$ in ${\bf Z}_p$. But really once you have multiplied by a uniform random element, it's not clear to me that you have any information left at all to help you determine anything about the polynomial.

Comment: @GerryMyerson "the information to determine anything about the polynomial" is the random values. Specifically, we can latter remove random values from Y's. This allows us to retrieve the original polynomial. The entire scenario is as following and I'll attach your answer that I concluded at the end. A have a polynomial $P_1$, he evaluates it at many $X$ values to obtain $Y$'s.Then multiplies each $Y_i$ by a distinct uniformly at random value to obtain $Y'_i$. B has different polynomial $P_2$, he also evaluates on the same $X$ values as A did to obtain $Z$'s.

Comment: Similarly he multiplies $Z_i$ by distinct uniformly at random value to obtain $Z'_i$.Then both send their $Y'_i$ , $Z'_i$ and the $X$ values to the untrusted server.The server should not be able to figure out anything about $P_1$ and $P_2$,given these information. Now the A or B can ask the server to multiply $Z'_i$ by $Y'_i$ values and send the result to A or B.These two client can exchange their random values, so they can remove it from the result. As far as I understood from your answer you're saying that the server cannot figure out the original polynomials.Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: As a side note, as we know to be able to remove that random values we can work on a field rather than Zp

Comment: @GerryMyerson I'll be pleased to have your idea about above scenario. Regards